# Why do I sometimes get "item size exceeded" message when batch-writing into DynamoDB?

Tags: python, json, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table whose items are long strings. These string are JSON messages converted into strings.

Each JSON message has a unique id (`eId` below) associated with it that is used as the hash key.

If a string is longer than certain max (`maxlen` below), I split it into pieces and create individual items for each piece and then I create a "parent" message that refers to those pieces. This way I am trying to avoid creating items bigger than the 64K limit.

I collect items into batches of length 25 and then batch-write into the table.

I am not using `maxlen = 30000`. Still from time to time, batch write throws the `Item size exceeds limit` exception. Here's the splitting code:

```
mStr = json.dumps(m,encoding='utf-8', ensure_ascii=False, sort_keys=True)
lStr = len(mStr)
if lStr > maxlen:
    np = int(math.ceil(float(lStr)/maxlen))
    log.info("Splitting message with id=%s of len=%d into %d pieces of upto %d" % (eId, lStr, np, maxlen))
    start=0
    parentMessage = ""
    for ip in range(np):
       fin=(ip+1)*maxlen
       ss = mStr[start:fin]
       eId_ss = eId + ("-part%dof%d" % (ip+1, np))
       item_data = {"split" : "0", "message" : ss}
       item = createNewItem(table,eId_ss,item_data)

       csP = cPickle.dumps(item)
       szP = sys.getsizeof(csP)
       log.info("%s: [%d : %d] = %d chars, item size %d" % (eId_ss,start,fin,len(ss),szP))

       items.append(item)
       item_eIds.append(eId_ss)

       parentMessage += (eId_ss + ";")
       start=fin

       item_data = {"split" : "1", "message" : parentMessage}
       item = createNewItem(table,eId,item_data)
       items.append(item)
       item_eIds.append(eId)
else:
```

What I noticed was that from time to time the line `sys.getsizeof(csP)` seems to produce values that are upto about 4 times larger than the length of the string piece `ss`. That does not happen often but I see it in the log. So I presume it happens from time to time that it generates an item that's bigger than 64K.

I, of course, can keep lowering `maxlen`. But since I don't understand how large items get generated, I don't know what value to pick. Plus, lower values of `maxlen` mean a lot more messages get split which slows down my code.

Questions:
1. Why does it sometimes generate items that are much bigger than the strings they "wrap"?
2. More importantly, is there a robust way of ensuring my items are not too big without having to lower `maxlen` to ridiculously low values?

Thx

aaaa

Answer (score 0):

You will have to re-structure the data. Dynamo DB has item limit of 64KB - This is also including the atrributes etc. So the effective size is even lesser.

Limits in DynamoDB - Amazon DynamoDB : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html

This tells how to re-structure data to work within these limits (like gzip etc)

Guidelines for Working With Items - Amazon DynamoDB : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForItems.html

Answer (score 0):

The length you are calculating is actually the number of characters in the string. Since you are using UTF-8, a single character can be up to 4 bytes long (that's why you sometimes see messages that are ~4x larger than you expect)

If you want to check the size in bytes in Python, you can use: `len(mStr.encode('utf-8'))`